# Implement push_back in OpenCV using EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I need to implement `push_back` in OpenCV using EmguCV. I used the add function in Matrix.
However, it does not seems to be working. Even though, I have added elements, matrix is empty.

Here is my OpenCV function:.

```
Mat labels(0, 1, CV_32FC1);
float label=atof(entryPath.filename().c_str());
labels.push_back(label);
```

And this is the EmguCV code I wrote:

```
Matrix<int> labels = new Matrix<int>(1, 1, 1);
int label = 1;
labels.Add(label);
```

Can someone help me to this conversion?

Comment: What do you mean by _it is not working_? Any exception or any other things?

Comment: No exception, values are not added either. :(

Comment: Did you solved the issue? I have the same problem here

Answer (score 1):

Just figured things out. This lines of code works for me:

```
firstMatrix.Mat.PushBack(secondMatrix.Mat);
```

Hope it will help someone